# checking variable is null in laravel blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the variable `$material_details->pricing=null`  I want to check the variable is set in laravel blade file.I have tried as

```
@isset($material_details->pricing)
 <tr>
   <td>price is not null</td>
 </tr>
@endisset
```

but no luck .How to check the variable is set or not in laravel 5.3 blade file.

Comment: Try `@if($material_details->pricing)  @endif`

Answer (score 38):

You can use either Null Coalescing or Elvis Operator

**Null Coalescing Operator**

```
{{ $material_details ?? 'second value' }} //object
{{ $material_details->property ?? 'second value' }} //Object Property
```

**Elvis Operator** (checks given value is empty or null)

```
{{ $material_details ?: 'default value' }} //Object
{{ $material_details->property ?: 'default value' }} //Object Property
```

Read on Elvis and Null coalescing operator.

Links:

**Elvis:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

**Null coalescing operator:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 24):

Try following code.

```php
@if(is_null($material_details))
    // whatever you need to do here
@else
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
@if(isset($material_details->pricing))
 <tr>
   <td>NOT NULL</td>
 </tr>
@else
 <tr>
   <td>NULL</td>
 </tr>
@endif
```

Or this

```
@if(empty($material_details->pricing))
 <tr>
   <td>NULL</td>
 </tr>
@else
 <tr>
   <td>NOT NULL</td>
 </tr>
@endif
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code will only print data if the variable hold, some value.

Try something like following :

```
@if(isset($material_details->pricing))
 <tr>
   <td>price is not null</td>
 </tr>

@else
 <tr>
   <td>null</td>
 </tr>

@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using laravel ternary operator as like below

```
{!! !empty($material_details->pricing) ? '<tr><td>price is not null</td></tr>' : '<tr><td>Empty</td</tr>' !!}
```

Comment: Why the `{!! !!}` here? Any reason why you can't do the standard and safer `{{ }}`?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use '@isset()' balde directive :

```
@isset($records)
    // $records is defined and is not null...
@endisset

@empty($records)
    // $records is "empty"...
@endempty
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
@if($material_details->pricing != null)
   <tr>
     <td>price is not null</td>
   </tr>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If are able to access your variable through {{ $material_details['pricing'] }} inside your blade file,
```

then this will work to check and append value:

```
{{ ($material_details['pricing'] == "null") ? "null value" : $material_details['pricing'] }}
```

To check and append elements :

```
@if($material_details['pricing'] != "null")
  <tr>
   <td>price is not null</td>
 </tr>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Laravel `isEmpty()` by chaining it to your collection on blade.

```
@if($data->quotes->isEmpty()) 
  //Empty
@else
// Not Empty
@endif
```

More info on Laravel API website [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty).