# Attempt to read property "degree" on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i have created a profile where users can add their education fields.

when there is no value in the database it throws an error. how can i get rid of this ? Attempt to read property "degree" on null.

```
public function myEducations()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Education','user_id')->orderByDesc('endDate');
    }
```

controller

```
 public function myProfile(\App\Models\User $user)
{

               $user = Auth::user();

    $education = $user->myEducations->first();

    return view('candidate.profile',compact('user','education'));
```

blade

```
{{ $education->degree }} - {{ $education->fieldOfStudy }}
```

Comment: This question is asked so often on Stackoverflow... If `$education` is `null`, then you can't access `->degree` or `->fieldOfStudy`. In your case, if your `$user` is `null`, or your `$user` doesn't have any `myEducations`, then your code will fail (as it currently is). You need to take steps to check your variables, like `if ($user) { ... }`, or `->firstOrFail()`, etc etc to handle these situations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [checking variable is null in laravel blade file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718494/checking-variable-is-null-in-laravel-blade-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users of you application are filling in their education details later only. You should ideally catch this condition when rendering your view. For example you could try the following:

```
@if ($education)
  {{ $education->degree }} - {{ $education->fieldOfStudy }}
@else
  <p>Education details not available</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inspect in an if statement $education->degree is not null.
If not null, degree has value, this part will render.
Else, it doesn't have value so else block appears in template.

```
@if(null !== $education->degree)
    {{ $education->degree }} - {{ $education->fieldOfStudy }}
@else
    // there is no degree
@endif
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.