# Curly brackets {{}} is deleting my null value laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am passing a variable that may be null value from controller to blade

When this variable is of a null value it causes an error in the following line where it says unexpected token,

```
'client_id': {{$current_client}},
```

[image]

Whats the correct syntax for this situation?

Comment: wrap it with a single quote, and give it a shot.
like `'client_id': '{{ $client_id }}'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [checking variable is null in laravel blade file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718494/checking-variable-is-null-in-laravel-blade-file)

Comment: do you mind reposting it as a comment so i can mark it as correct? Kindly explain the rationale behind it too thanks! @MiteshRathod

Comment: @YeoBryan does it works?

Comment: @YeoBryan I have commented answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this in back ticks i.e.

```
'client_id': `{{$current_client}}`
```

if there's a null value, it'll return empty not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in a single quote,

```
'client_id': '{{ $client_id }}'
```